# trucate DB table in magento

Tags: mysql, magento2

Magento itself provides some kind of API Structure (like the API System inside Laravel Nova) for all kind of requests, we need to extend that endpoints to provide a functionality to just truncate the inventory table in DB

the reason for that: products and stocks coming from an external Software and will be placed inside magento, and because of that we ran into stock count problems between magento and external Software

there is still no official solution for that problem from Adobe so the workaround is to empty that specific table in DB everytime we import the new stocks

Comment: OK, and what's your question here? Is this a mysql question (i.e. you do not know how to truncate a table in mysql) or is this a magento question (i.e. you do not know how to issue the relevant sql statement or integrating the truncate with other parts of magento)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.